# ASCII IP to Host Byte Order Long

Tags: python, ip

I need to convert an ASCII IP `192.168.1.1` to the host byte order. I attempted to use the following function with no success.

```
import socket
socket.ntohl(socket.inet_aton('192.168.1.1'))
```

However the ntohl function throws an error saying it cannot accept strings, but requires an int/long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.inet_anon()` function returns a packed 32-bit binary value; you could use the [`struct` module](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html) to turn that into an integer:

```
import struct
import socket

socket.ntohl(struct.unpack('I', socket.inet_aton('192.168.1.1'))[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> socket.inet_aton.__doc__
'inet_aton(string) -> packed 32-bit IP representation\n\nConvert an IP address in string format (123.45.67.89) to the 32-bit packed\nbinary format used in low-level network functions.'

import struct
struct.unpack('>L', socket.inet_aton('192.168.1.1'))[0]
```